# I want to be able to overlay the image with another uploaded image

Tags: image, upload

I wanna do small e-shop and I need upload customers image and display it on for example cup like a motive so there will be on the background clean white cup and the customer will upload picture and this picture will be displayed in the center of the cup. If there is plug like these of somenting please let me know. TY!

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, hence it's off-topic here. I suggest you try a plain old web search first, then write some code and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two Imagagemagick forum users who have some code to do this:
[fmw42's cylinderize script](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/cylinderize/index.php) - you will need to pay to use commercially and 
[snibgo's coffee cup script](http://im.snibgo.com/coffmug.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_canvas.asp) HTML5 tag and then use the method [drawImage()](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp) to draw the white cup and use the same method for drawing the user picture on top of it? Otherwise you could use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to combine the two images on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you could create a variable to hold the default image, e.g. `$img = 'default.jpg';` Then check if an img has been uploaded and update $img accordingly, e.g. `$img = $_POST['img_upload'];`

In the mark-up you echo $img to display either the default or uploaded img. I suppose you get the idea and can fill-in the missing bits.